# Money and TypeError: __init__() takes from 1 to 2 positional arguments but 3 were given

Tags: python, python-3.x

Python newbie here.  I use PyDev on Eclipse.

I am writing a program to process my bank transactions.  I use the Money package (1.3.0).  The program worked fine until I learned that you could create a currency preset variant of Money (as shown [on this page](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/money/1.3.0).

The following snipped works fine when I use Money, but it gives an error when I use my USD preset:

```
from money import Money
class USD(Money):
    def __init__(self, amount='0'):
        super().__init__(amount=amount, currency='USD')
a = Money(0,'USD')
b = Money(-360,'USD')
a += b
print(a)
c = USD(0)
d = USD(-360)
c += d
print(c)
```

(The real purpose of the print() statements is for a convenient place to set a breakpoint.)

I get this error:

```
File "D:\Dev\mymoney\mymoney.py", line 11, in <module>
  c += d
File "C:\Program Files\Python35\lib\site-packages\money\money.py", line 119, in __add__
   return self.__class__(amount, self._currency)
TypeError: __init__() takes from 1 to 2 positional arguments but 3 were given
```

I would like to know how to fix my code so it works properly, but I need to understand what the problem is.  For the latter, either your explanation or a pointer to something in the documentation from which I can learn would be helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because in the `__add__` method defined in the [source code here](https://github.com/carlospalol/money/blob/master/src/money/money.py), a new class is returned passing both `amount` *and* `self._currency` to `__init__`.

```
def __add__(self, other):
    if isinstance(other, Money):
        if other.currency != self._currency:
            raise CurrencyMismatch(self._currency, other.currency, '+')
        other = other.amount
    amount = self._amount + other
    return self.__class__(amount, self._currency)
```

But your currency preset subclass only consumes an amount, and not a currency. Hence, you are passing it too many positional arguments.

Your choices would be to not subclass `Money` for currency presets (my recommendation, I don't see much of a point), change the `__init__` method of your subclass to accept a default parameter set to the respective currency for that subclass, or override methods like `__add__` to not pass a currency argument  to `__init__`, by having something like `return self.__class__(amount)` instead. Don't do the latter though, it's not necessary.

Comment: Because what I am doing is exactly according to the documentation, I decided to try to report it as a bug.  I learned that this is a known issue.  See https://github.com/carlospalol/money/issues/19.  Issue 20 is a suggestion to improve support for single-currency subclasses.  Since I am not knowledgeable enough to submit a fix myself, I will keep things simple and just use the non-subclassed approach, for now.

Comment: It is puzzling to me that the message talked about an __init__ function as being the problem.  The line of code it points to is a return that has __class__.  I have not studied classes in Python yet, but I gather that the __class__ notation refers to creating a new instance of the class, which would presumably invoke its __init__ function.  Is that about right?

Comment: That is precisely correct, yes :) and `+=` invokes `__add__` for the class, which is not overridden in the subclass.